# React UseEffect Hook - value updates within hook but not within body of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using a font-picker-react package to render fonts using a Google Font API. 
Each time a new font is selected from a dropdown, I want to use this to update a field value.
Currently, within the useEffect hook, the 'value' correctly updates. However, when console logging 'value' within the body of the component, this doesn't update and I'm not sure why.

```
export function FontPickerInputField<T = any>({ field }: FontPickerSidebarProps<T>) {
    const placeholderFont: string = 'Open Sans';
    const [fontFamily, setFontFamily] = useState(placeholderFont);
    let { value, name } = field;
    const fontFormat: string = fontFamily.replace(/\s/g, '+');
    const updatedFont = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=${fontFormat}:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap`;
    const [googleFontLink, setGoogleFontLink] = useState(updatedFont);

    useEffect(() => {
        setGoogleFontLink(updatedFont);
        value = googleFontLink;
    }, [fontFamily]);

    return (
        <StyledContainer>
            <FontPicker
                apiKey="MY-API-KEY"
                activeFontFamily={fontFamily}
                onChange={({ family }) => setFontFamily(family)}
                limit={100}
                sort={'popularity'}
            />
        </StyledContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: `field` is a prop passed from the parent, so its `value` can't be updated from the children. Could you share where does this `field` prop come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `useState` hook. `value` comes from the prop and if you want to update it with the state change, initialize like  -

```
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(value); // initialize with the value from the props
```

now in your use hook when you want to update current value -

```
useEffect(() => {
        setGoogleFontLink(updatedFont);
        setCurrentValue(googleFontLink);
    }, [fontFamily]);
```

You can see then `currentValue` is updated in body also.